# void pointer : what is wrong?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I have a 3-byte variable, but since there are no 3byte variables in C , I use a long 32bit instead. Then I want to send ONLY 3 bytes on the bus. I access the bus as ext Ram 8-bit width.
To send only 3 bytes, i need to break the long value into 2-byte(a short) and 1-byte ( a char).

what I do is:

```
typedef union
{
  unsigned char b[3];
  unsigned long lng;
} lng_array;

void SendLong(unsigned long d)
{   
  volatile void* c =(void*)Dat; // Dat is a #defined long number equal to the address on the bus that data must be sent
  lng_array tmp;
  tmp.lng=d;
  *c=*(unsigned short*)(&tmp.b[0]);  // Error
  *c=*(unsigned char*)(&tmp.b[2]);   // Error
}
```

for the 2 "*c=" lines I get an error  :"Error   36  invalid use of void expression  "

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For a 3 byte variable you could use an array of 3  `  unsigned char  `s.  Assign each byte individually, and use by having a pointer to the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*c` makes no sense (cannot be derefenced) if the `c` is a `void*` since the compiler would need to know the size of it. Cast it again to a `unsigned char*`, like: `*((unsigned char*)(c)) = (unsigned char*)(&tmp.b[2]);`

Answer (score 2):

Since the variable `c` is of type pointer to void, you cannot dereference it (e.g. reading/writing `*c`). If you want to access the memory it points to you must add a type cast.

The C standard states that

> 6.3.2.2 void
>
> The (nonexistent) value of a void expression (an expression that has
>   type void) shall not be used in any way, ...

and since `c` is of type pointer to void dereferencing it produces a void expression which then cannot be used for anything. Whatever there is on the other side of the equal sign is irrelevant with regards to this.

Comment: Yes, ok I know that one is not allowed to dereference diectly on void pointers.. but I assumed, that since there is some casting in the same line, the compiler would treat c as the type is is pointing to, at least for that line. I guess my assuption was wrong, but then the casting is useless because 
c=&tmp.b[0];
is equal to
c=(unsigned short*)&tmp.b[0];